# How to get current course ID in angular?

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs

I have this lines of code

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this._store.select(AuthSelectors.isLoggedIn).pipe(
            takeUntil(this.destroySubject$),
            tap((isLoggedIn) => {
                if (isLoggedIn) {
                    this._store.select(selectCourseToBeEnrolled)
                        .pipe(filter(value => !!value), first())
                        .subscribe(course => this._store.dispatch(enrollWhatToLearnCourse({
                                id: course.id,
                                title: course.title,
                                enroll: false
                            }))
                        );
                }
            }),
            tap(() => this._store.dispatch(loadOneCourse({}))) //here
        ).subscribe();
    }
```

Now where did I comment I need to pass ID of current course by props. Any ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```js
this._store.select(AuthSelectors.isLoggedIn).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroySubject$),
    switchMap(isLoggedIn => {
        if (!isLoggedIn) return EMPTY
        return this._store.select(selectCourseToBeEnrolled)
                   .pipe(
                       filter(value => !!value), 
                       first(),
                       tap(course => {
                           this._store.dispatch(enrollWhatToLearnCourse({
                                id: course.id,
                                title: course.title,
                                enroll: false
                            })
                       })
                   )
    }),
    tap((course) => this._store.dispatch(loadOneCourse({})))
).subscribe()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by merging the inner observable with source one using one of the higher mapping operators such as `switchMap`, `mergeMap`, then the `course` will be available in the next operators (`tap`).

You can try the following:

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._store
      .select(AuthSelectors.isLoggedIn)
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroySubject$),
        switchMap((isLoggedIn) => {
          if (isLoggedIn) {
            return this._store.select(selectCourseToBeEnrolled).pipe(
              filter((value) => !!value),
              first()
            );
          }
          // return null if the user is not logged in
          return of(null);
        }),
        // only pass it to the following operators if the course has a value
        filter((course) => !!course),
        // if the couse has value, then you can use it directly within the next taps
        tap((course) => {
          this._store.dispatch(
            enrollWhatToLearnCourse({
              id: course.id,
              title: course.title,
              enroll: false,
            })
          );
        }),
        tap((course) => this._store.dispatch(loadOneCourse({ course })))
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

You can take a look at the following blog for more details about
`RxJS` higher mapping operators:
https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/